# Javascript redirect vulnerability

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, security, redirect

Say I store the url path in a query parameter like `/?return_back_to=/foo/bar`

Then pass this to some external auth service like Microsoft, which does the login and returns to the same url with my query parameter.

At this point, is it safe to get the value from the query parameter and redirect using React `navigate()` to this url? Or is this considered an "open redirect vulnerability" ?

Answer (score 1):

On the surface, as long as you follow a bunch of best practices and validate the query parameter, it should be save to use it, and would not be "open redirect vulnerability".

You mentioned using Microsoft auth service, which i personally don't have that much experience with, but I have used firebase and google auth a lot and I know that they automatically check and if the redirect URL is not whitelisted it will not work. firebase automatically adds localhost and your app domain to whitelist and you can add more if you have external links that you would like your users to be redirected to.

source 1: https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6400741?hl=en

source 2: https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9021429?hl=en

in terms of it being safe to use react `navigate()` when users are actually back to your app, you should make sure to either check the URL against a local whitelist or just add your app domain to the URL before redirecting the users.

`navigate({safeDomain} + {query parameter})`

Although I should mention that if by `navigate()` you are refering to `useNavigate()` hook, I dont think you can use it for that, and you need to use `redirect()` .

some more useful information for [mitigating against open redirect vulnerability](https://learn.snyk.io/lessons/open-redirect/javascript/#bvrtrmcperlxm)

I hope this was helpful!

Comment: I think `redirect()` and `navigate()` would both work.  It depends on where in the component the redirection is executed.  `redirect()` works in the new v6.4 style `loader` and `action` props of the `Route`. https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/overview#redirects  But `navigate(path, { replace: true })` inside the content will have the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on who is calling that endpoint. Well known identity providers will require you to set allowed redirect urls, and will only send back the authorized ones (the ones you set up). So they will only call the callback if it's ok, so you can redirect securely.

However, anybody else might use this url (link to it) with a different parameter, to which you don't want to naviigate, that would be an open redirect. So you need to make sure that the request actually originates from a trusted source, ie. from Azure AD. Depending on what flow you are implementing, you can either validate a token you received to make sure it is a valid request, or at the very least you can check an Origin / Referer header to see who the caller is (it's not possible to alter Origin or Referer in Javascript, so an attacker cannot have a legitimate user visit a link with a malicious redirect, with an Origin from Microsoft).

Also if you only redirect in your own origin (domain), you can and should add validation that the redirect path (`return_back_to`) is internal, like for example starts with a `/` and/or does not contain `://`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't completely agree with what has been said in the other answers.

Indeed, the return URL that may contain any information using this mechanism will expose this data to all kinds of attacks.

Let's take an example, if the return url is for example the user's dashboard, the url could be of the type `/users/<id or name of the user>`

Moreover, all this also depends on the checks that are implemented on your side.

Let's say an attacker tries to use your url to override the url legitimately returned by your authentication service: `http://callback.url/?return_back_to=http://malicious.example.com`

If you do not handle the data received correctly, this will lead to potential security breaches.

For all of these reasons (and many others) i f think you should avoid passing and using directly web (or filesystem) paths directly in a GET or POST var.

Instead, you can evaluate the possibility of passing only the information you need to identify the target and the construct the url in your callback script before passing it to `navigate()`.

Also, i don't know if you do that, avoid passing any numerical ID in POST and GET vars. Instead generate an alphanumeric unique ID to avoid ID predicting from attaquers.

For having more information about Web security i recommande learning the OWASP Top Ten rules : https://owasp.org/www-project-top-ten/

This is a good entry point to building secured web apps.

Comment: Exposing ids can be a problem, or not at all, it depends on the application. I don't think it's bad practice to expose ids *in general*, and unless there is something in the threat model that indicates that. Ids should not be secrets. Having this "secret ids" mindset can in fact lead to security issues if ids are thought of as unknown to attackers. An attacker linking to the redirect endpoint with a malicious redirect url is exactly why I recommended validation and redirecting to internal urls only, and also checking the origin as an additional layer.

Comment: You are right though that only passing values of an enum and decide redirect target based on that is even better if possible, this is a very strong form of input validation. Generating a random token just for this purpose is usually overkill, but can be justified in some cases, that's right. You are also right that one must be careful not to include sensitive info in the redirect url, as that will be exposed, but sensitive info should never be in urls anyway.

Comment: @GaborLengyel I personaly don't aggree about **numeric** ids in url. For example, if you have an url like this one: `/print_invoices.php?user_id=125` An attacker can try replacing 125 by 126, 127, etc. Numerical ids are predictable. Thus, using this an attacker can gain important informations about the target. For example, if the script return valuable error messages, he can guess what are valid user ids. if the ids are alphanumeric, an attacker won't be able to try. So, `/print_invoices.php?user_id=a5fg8y2v2f2d` is better. This alpha_id can be generated by the SQL that INSERT a new user.

Comment: The alphanumeric id in your example has about 62 bits of entropy. It could be brute forced in reasonable time in a distributed attack if the space is filled with many valid ones. Using them might tempt a developer to not think about actual access control / authorization that must be implemented anyway. I'm not saying this does not have a role *sometimes*. I'm just saying that probably more often than not, numeric ids are ok, obviously with emphasis on proper access control, which has to be implemented correctly, alphanumeric ids or not.

Comment: Also if numeric is not enough, you probably want cryptographically random, which is not just alphanumeric. There are those cases when you need that, but I wouldn't say that's all the time, for example because of the additional complexity, which itself increases the attack surface and  chance of bugs that might affect securtiy. Simplicity sometimes has its value too.

Comment: @ GaborLengyel you're right about simplicity. About my example, it is just an example of course that alphanumerical ids must be long enougth. But as you certainly know So comments are limited in size and just reduce the id size to fit the comment size.
I aggre that an attacker that really want to crack a website will try many approach. But using alpha ids will reduce the number of attackes that can attack the site. If you website is very important, i guess you will put other security layers to deal with different attack types.

Comment: Everything is crackable, if you pay the price. The good security level is the one that have the good price relative to what you need to protect. So, using unpredictable ids i not the ultimate solution, but this will considerabiliy reduce the vulnerability of your site.